# No SPS/PPS in h264 mpegtsmux output in GStreamer 1.xx?

Tags: h.264, gstreamer

The following pipeline (to turn .mp4 into .ts) works fine in GStreamer 0.10:

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=/tmp/temp.mp4 ! qtdemux  ! h264parse !  mpegtsmux name=mux ! filesink location=/tmp/output.ts
```

But the same pipeline with GStreamer 1.0.2 produces an output.ts that isn't playable. As far as I can see in the TS output, there don't seem to be any SPS/PPS startcodes (they are present in the output from 0.10).

The output from the h264parse element appears to be identical between the two versions.

I looked at the source for the latest mpegtsmux, and there is no longer any mention of SPS/PPS anywhere. In fact, a whole file mpegtsmux_h264.c seems to have disappeared.

How does new mpegtsmux work in this respect? Do I need to add extra things upstream in the pipeline? Or add properties to mpegtsmux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a bug in h264parse, fixed in newest GStreamer code.